# How can I merge two snippets of text that both contain a desired keyword?

Tags: python, spyder

I have a program that pulls out text around a specific keyword. I'm trying to modify it so that if two keywords are close enough together, it just shows one longer snippet of text instead of two individual snippets.

My current code, below, adds words after the keyword to a list and resets the counter if another keyword is found. However, I've found two problems with this. The first is that the data rate limit in my spyder notebook is exceeded, and I haven't been able to deal with that. The second is that though this would make a longer snippet, it wouldn't get rid of the duplicate.

Does anyone know a way to get rid of the duplicate snippet, or know how to merge the snippets in a way that doesn't exceed the data rate limit (or know how to change the spyder rate limit)? Thank you!!

```
def occurs(word1, word2, file, filewrite):
    import os


    infile = open(file,'r')     #opens file, reads, splits into lines
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()
    infile.close()
    wordlist = [word1, word2]       #this list allows for multiple words
    wordsString = ''.join(lines)      #splits file into individual words
    words = wordsString.split()


    f = open(file, 'w')
    f.write("start")
    f.write(os.linesep)

    g = open(filewrite,'w')
    g.write("start")
    g.write(os.linesep)    

    for item in wordlist:        #multiple words
        matches = [i for i, w in enumerate(words) if w.lower().find(item) != -1] 
              #above line goes through lines, finds the specific words we want

        for m in matches:        #next three lines find each instance of the word, print out surrounding words
            list = []
            s = ""
            l = " ".join(words[m-20:m+1])
            j = 0
            while j < 20:
                list.append(words[m+i])
                j = j+1
                if words[m+i] == word1 or words[m+i] == word2:
                    j = 0
                    print (list)
            k = " ".join(list)

            f.write(f"{s}...{l}{k}...")          #writes the data to the external file
            f.write(os.linesep)
            g.write(str(m))
            g.write(os.linesep)
    f.close
    g.close
```

Comment: First off, you should not overwrite the builtin `list` class, call it 'lst' instead. Second, where does i come from here: `list.append(words[m+i])`

Comment: oh, i was the variable name I had before I switched to j; must have forgotten to switch that one. The problems were still there before I switched the variable name, though